# Chat room annoyance?

Tags: support, status-norepro

Nobody's actually annoying me or anything. It is actually this annoying thing that is happening when I click on "Leave" in a chatroom.

Everytime I click on "Leave", instead of redirecting me to [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=anime.stackexchange.com) with all of the anime chat rooms on the site, it takes me here:

[image]

Long story short: It is extremely annoying and I have to go to the stackexchange tab, click on Anime and Manga and then click on chat again to go back and see the rest of the Anime and Manga site rooms.

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening? Is there a setting somewhere that can assist me or solve this that I haven't seen?

Comment: Write a script that will redirect you wherever you want after logging out. I don't know exactly how, but from what I know, it could be a javascript bookmarklet that logs you out and then changes the current page address to where you want. You can probably ask in some programmers chat room for the code.

Comment: Try once while in the room: Click the "site rooms", make sure that you get the anime rooms, then try to leave the room again.

Comment: @user1306322- Not very good at programing/coding. xD

Comment: @MadaraUchiha- I wasn't quite sure about what you mean't, but did you mean go into a anime chat room and try to leave, because it still does the same thing.

Comment: You gotta be in some other anime room I think. Try joining HoiHoi-san's testbed, leave the Maid Cafe and see where you end up. Also why do you have to manually leave the chatroom anyway?

Comment: @user1306322- Oh wait, I found out what it was. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wait, sorry, I know what was causing the problem. I have this extension on Google Chrome called KB SSL Enforcer (Don't ask me why I have this xD). I just needed to disable it for stackexchange, but now my redirects are working fine now and I am getting correctly redirected to all the anime chat rooms when I click "Leave".